# Highlighting curl code snippet in react syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, react-syntax-highlighter

I was trying to highlight curl code snippet in my react application.
I am using `react-syntax-highlighter` for the same.

The problem, curl code is not coming properly aligned. below my code snippet.

```
import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { github } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

const getCurlSnippet = (loadId, text) =>{
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const PARSE_API_URL = "API URL";
  return `curl ${PARSE_API_URL} \
    -H 'authorization: ${token}' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{"loadId":"${loadId}","text":"${text}"}' \
    --compressed`;
}

const getHighlightSnippet = () => (
    <SyntaxHighlighter
        language="curl"
        style={github}
        customStyle={{borderRadius: "12px", padding: "16px", background: "rgb(227 224 224)"}}
    >
        {getCurlSnippet("U134IJ", "Hello world")}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>
);
```

Here is the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-flower-x11vj)

Output is coming in single line, instead of vertically aligned.

Comment: maybe you need to pass `language="bash"` not curl.

Comment: tried also, syntax is highlighting, but it’s coming in one line.

Comment: try with `\n` instead.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-flower-x11vj
tried in this.

Comment: add `\n`  in your code. rather than only `\\` . `\n`  move the code to next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bash` as a language in your `SyntaxHighlighter` Component props rather than `curl` and

Instead writing only `\` in the end of each line, write `\n`, which move code to the next line.

Here the working code of yours:

```js
// app.js

import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { github } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs";
import "./styles.css";

const getCurlSnippet = (loadId, text) => {
  const authToken = "toekn";
  const PARSE_API_URL = "API_URL";
  return `curl '${PARSE_API_URL}' \n
    -H 'authorization: ${authToken}' \n
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \n
    --data-raw '{"loadId":"${loadId}","text":"${text}"}' \n
    --compressed`;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SyntaxHighlighter
        language="bash"
        style={github}
        customStyle={{
          borderRadius: "12px",
          padding: "16px",
          background: "rgb(227 224 224)"
        }}
      >
        {getCurlSnippet("U134IJ", "Hello world")}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: oh ho, too silly, was almost there, thanks, it works perfectly:)